# Avoiding SPACE and ENTER keys with wxButton

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Working with wxWidgets on W7, with focus over a wxButton, I would like to avoid button activation pressing SPACE or ENTER keys.

The button should reacts only on click events.

What is the right way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this by catching `EVT_KEY_DOWN` event and doing nothing in your handler, but I'd strongly recommend not doing this. Users expect these keys to work with the buttons and if you want something that doesn't react to the keyboard, you should use some other (custom) control and not `wxButton` at all.